# JQuery Dialog not opening second time while loading an aspx page inside the dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have checked with the similar questions but none gave me a solution... that's why posting this question.. So please provide me a solution instead of voting down...

I am loading an aspx page inside my dialog. It works fine for the first time, But if i close and reopen it for the second time.. its not getting opened..

This is my default.aspx where i am handling the script for dialog

```
       <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#thedialog").dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            position: 'center',
                            width: 900,
                            open: function() {
                            $('#thedialog').load("AddDetails.aspx");
                            }
                        });

                         $('#link').click(function() {
                          $('#thedialog').dialog('open');

                        });

                    });
             </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="thedialog" style="display: none; overflow: hidden">
           <span id="link" style="color: #88b807; margin-left: 839px;
                            margin-top: -12px; cursor: pointer; display: block">Create</span>
</div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

This is my AddDetails.aspx

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table id="table" style="border-spacing: 7px 7px; margin-left: 5px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="SubHeading">Private Space Name </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_spacename" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="SubHeading">Private Space Description </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_spacedesc" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Instead of loading a page if i just simply open a dialog it is getting opened but its not opening if i load a page inside the dialog...

Help...

Comment: Is the dialog itself not opening or is the dialog opening but the contents are empty or the same contents as before?

Comment: Using the js you provided I have no problems - each time the dialog opens it makes a new async call to the address specified and loads it in the dialog.
Is there more js or html on the page? I can't see an element with id of link (to open the dialog) or a method of submitting the form you load.

Comment: @Miguel-F the dialog is not opening..

Comment: @KevD I have edited in my question.. Pls see my edit

Comment: Do you really not have a closing `</div>` tag for your dialog html or is that just in your post?  ("thedialog" div)

Comment: @Miguel-F Sorry for the late response.. I have missed the closing tag here alone.. I have edited it now.. It was fine in my original code..

Answer (score 0):

From your updated code it looks like the link that you are clicking is located inside the div that you are loading your ajax call into. If this is the case then your click event to load the dialog is only being bound once (on the initial page load). When the link element is loaded once more (I'm assuming it's in the ajax response being loaded), it no longer has the click event bound to it.

To get around this you can either:

1. Move your link outside of the #thedialog div element (it doesn't look like it's being closed properly right now)
2. Amend you javascript to add a delegate so that that the click event fires on that type of element even if the page (DOM) changes, something like:

   ```
   $("#thedialog").delegate("#link", "click", function () {
       $('#thedialog').dialog('open');
       return false;
   });
   ```

   Option 2 might produce some odd results though if there is a #link element in the dialog itself though - I'd go with the first option if this fixes the issue.

---

**UPDATE:**

The above works on my browser, but to be sure I'd try the following code and see if it works, it might be that the versions of jquery / jquery ui are out of whack or not up to date, I guess.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test dialog page</title>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#thedialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            position: 'center',
            width: 900,
            height: 300,
            open: function () {
                $('#thedialog').load("AddDetails.aspx");
            }
        });

        $('#link').click(function () {
            $('#thedialog').dialog('open');
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="thedialog" style="display: none; overflow: hidden">
</div>
<span id="link" style="color: #88b807; cursor: pointer; display: block">Create</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Other things I would try / recommend:

- Remove the wrapping body tags from AddDetails.aspx (unless you're
  using it in a non-ajax way). Also make sure it's not referencing a master page.
- Make sure that there is no other javascript that is being run on the page - no
  scripts referenced in the AddDetails page for instance.
- If you're still having issues then try looking in the Console in Firebug or the equivalent in another browser - is an error being reported or is it failing silently?

Comment: I've added to the answer with the code that I'm using which is working okay - give it a whirl and see if it still fails.